# Single WCF Service for all functionality

Tags: c#, wcf

I have created wcf service and I want to create single service for all the functionalities.

so I have used partial class and try to achieve it like this.

> FileName:-IMainService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMainService
{       
    [OperationContract]
    void DoWork();
}
```

> FileName:-MainService.svc

```
 public partial class MainService : IMainService
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

> FileName:-IProductService.cs

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProductService
{       
    [OperationContract]
    void GetProducts();
}
```

> FileName:-ProductService.svc

```
 public partial class MainService : IProductService
    {
        public void GetProducts()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

When I referenced the service in the application I can see two clients, MainServiceClient & ProductServiceClient. These names I guess based on file names and both contains the methods belong to there files for example: MainServiceClient has Dowork & ProductServiceClient has GetProducts.

I beleive I am in wrong track, Can somebody suggest me how do I achieve single service concept.

**EDIT:**

- The idea behind multiple interfaces and service files are
  maintainablity.
- We have lots of methods (100+) so I dont want to put everything on one
  service file so I splitted it.

Comment: Why do you have 2 interfaces then? I suppose you could just have a single interface and so a single service, but I doubt that would be a good idea.

Comment: Why not you have a single WCF service with both of your methods?

Comment: The idea behind multiple interfaces and multiple files are maintainablity.

Comment: How about a partial class? You could have one code file with the complete interface definition, but then implement the class so that you have one code file for each method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would just create a new service interface which includes both other service interfaces. And the service class then implements the joined interface.

something like this:

```
public interface IJoinedService : IProductService, IMainService
{
}

public class JoinedService : IJoinedService
{
   private ProductService _productService;
   public void GetProducts()
   {
     _productService.GetProducts();
   }
}
```

Comment: I would skip the IJoinedService and let JoinedService inherit from both directly

Comment: In ProductService, should I implement IProductService also ?

Comment: In JoinedService, I have to declare all service objects (like ProductService,OrderService etc) where do I initialize them ?

Answer (score 0):

why not something like this:

```
public class MainService : IProductService, IMainService
{
  MainService mMain = new MainService();
  ProductService mProduct = new ProductService();

  public void ImplementedMainServiceFunction()
  {
    mMain.DoSomething();
  }

  public void ImplementedProductServiceFunction(string s)
  {
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
      mProduct.DoSomething();
  }
}
```

Like this there's  one implementing class which takes care of parameter checking and the actual logic can assume that the parameters are checked already giving you clearer/shorter code. And the logic is divided over multiple files too.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am looking for something splitted not consolidated.